# Jquery not gathering textarea values and not sending arrays to php under specific conditions

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a system that gets the value of all textareas into one array and then send it to php for processing, if a page only has textareas with textbox like here:

```
<div class='form-group'>
     <textarea class='col-sm-2' id='" + counter + "'></textarea>
     <div class='col-sm-10'>
         <input type='text' class='form-control'></input>
     </div>
</div>
```

Everything goes fine. However if the page includes radio boxes:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <textarea class='col-sm-2' id='" + counter + "'></textarea>
    <div class='radio'>
        <input type='radio' name='optradio'></input>
        <textarea class='col-sm-2' id='" + counter + "'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='radio'>
        <input type='radio' name='optradio'></input>
        <textarea id='" + counter + "'></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery code does not collect all textareas and does not successfully send it to the php code for processing.

```
    $("#save").click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            form1[i].push($("#" + i).val());
        }
        $.post("FormResponse.php", {form: form1, formid:$("#formnum").val()}, function (response, status) {
          document.write(response);
        });
```

**Update:**

I changed my jquery code around to get both the type and the textarea values in one place and it still doesn't work. I didn't want to use objects because I want it to be easy for my php code to differentiate which textareas belong to which inputs.

Here is the code revision:

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    var ind = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputcounter; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("input#" + i) !== null) {
            form1.push($("input#" + i).type());
            ind = ind + 1;
        } 
        form1[ind].push($("textarea#" + i).val());
    }
    document.write(form1);
    $.post("FormResponse.php", {form: form1, formid: $("#formnum").val()}, function (response, status) {
        document.write(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but try this.

```
 $("#save").click(function () {

var data = {};

$.each($('textarea'),function(){
var $this = $(this);
data[$this.id] = $this.val();
})

$.post("FormResponse.php",data,function(rep){
console.log(rep);
});

});
```

**Edit**

I have no idea what your comment means.

1. You do realize that you sending a object in your code right?
2. The PHP code still accesses the data in the same way.
3. If you mean that you don't know what index the data will be in, then try the code below.

   ```
   $("#save").click(function () {

    var data = {};

    $.each($('textarea'),function(){
     var $this = $(this);
    data[$this.id] = $this.val();
   })

    $.post("FormResponse.php",{form:data, formid:$("#formnum").val()},function(rep){
   console.log(rep);
   });

   });
   ```

Comment: I don't want to use objects because I want it to be easy for my php code to differentiate which textareas belong to which inputs.